# ionic 4 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview toBack:true not working

Tags: android, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

1. I am Working on ionic 4 angular type application
2. I am want custom camera application
3. so that i am using camera-preview cordova plugins

In my componenet TS

```
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions,CameraPreviewPictureOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';

 private cameraPreview: CameraPreview

 taskphoto(){
this.imgurl = ''
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(this.cameraOpts).then(res=>{
     // this.cameraPreview.
     console.log(res);
      this.imgurl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.imgurl =''
      //this.imgurl = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
      alert(err)
    });
```

}

in HTML

```
<ion-fab class="fbtn"  vertical="bottom" (click)="takePicture()" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
<ion-fab  class="fbtn" vertical="bottom" (click)="stop()" horizontal="start" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
<ion-fab  class="fbtn" vertical="bottom" (click)="switchCamera()" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="repeat"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

[image]

so when i am build camera no showing but capture sound are working ,

toback:false means camera comes my designs are hidding,

also that in index.html i am add

```
  html, body, .ion-app, .ion-content {
```

background-color: transparent;
}

and component scss i am  add

```
 ion-content {--background-color: transparent !important}

body.camera-transparent, .camera-transparent ion-nav-view, .camera-transparent ion-view { background-color: transparent !important; }
```

this lines still not working

Comment: html, body, .ion-app, .ion-content { background-color: transparent; }

Comment: i tried but not coming, In exact file , or any project example are there ??

Comment: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/247#issuecomment-321038265

Comment: Check this link....

Comment: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/247#issuecomment-410462719

Comment: @MostafaHarb not working  bro i am tried , ima share my git link please check bro :   https://gitlab.com/sandy1198/camera-test